# related to image pixels distribution

Tags: tensorflow

in tensor flow example of image recognition they have loaded images,in which pixel value range from 0-255. But before feeding these images to neural network they divided them by 255 why is that so.

train_images = train_images / 255.0

test_images = test_images / 255.0

like this they have done.

can anyone give suggestion on this.

Comment: to make it in range 0 to 1.

Comment: Please read [this](https://becominghuman.ai/image-data-pre-processing-for-neural-networks-498289068258) about normalizing image inputs.